# GET http://localhost: postman

Tags: node.js, angular, https, mean-stack, postman

I'm using MEAN stack as my back-end. this is my server js file

```
const users = require('./routes/users');
app.get('/', (req, res) => { 
    res.send('Invalid endpoint');
});
```

This is my routes file users.js

```
router.get('/jobdetail', function(req,res) {
  console.log('fetching jobs');
  jobDetails.find({}, (err,jobs) => {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
    else {
      res.json(jobs);
    }
  });
});
```

when I run it the postman bu url:

> localhost:3000/api/jobdetail

Instead of the data from MongoDB I get the response as

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Error</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/D11634C0-514E-C94E-9DFD-54EBD0B16E5F/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <pre>Cannot GET /api/jobdetail</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: We need to see more of your code - how/where have you mounted the router, the order of middlewares etc.

Comment: It looks like you're missing `/api` in your route definition i.e. `router.get('/api/jobdetail`,..` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var api = require('../routes/users.js');
app.use('/api', api);
```

in your routes/users.js file :

```
    var mongoose =require('mongoose');
    var router = require('express').Router();
    var conn = mongoose.connection;
    conn.once("open", () => {
        router.get('/jobdetail', function(req, res) {
           jobDetails.find({}, (err,jobs) => {
              if(err) {
              console.log(err);
              }
              else {
               res.json(jobs);
               }
            });
        });
    });
    module.exports = router;
```